# How to fetch next date from given start date according to given days

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have one table called **Days** having following fields

```
StartDate   Days
17-06-2015  Wednesday,Friday,Monday
```

I want to fetch next date from `start date` according to days mentioned in days column

**For Ex.**

```
Date         Day
17-06-2015   Wednesday
19-06-2015   Friday
22-06-2015   Monday
```

Comment: mysql or sql server solution you want ?

Comment: startdate contain only one value ??or table has multiple startdates ??

Comment: it has only one value

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Sql-Server **DATEADD(datepart,number,date)** to add dates.

And it would be easier to get some logic to find the the number to be added from the days of week.

You can have days represented as numbers like

Sunday - 1, Monday - 2, Tuesday -3 and so on,

This way you would easily get the part to be added.
You will also need provision for cases like where Monday falls after Wed;
Where It would be Sat(7) - Wed(5) + Monday (2).

Hope this gives you some rough logic to move forward.